# API Connect on Bluemix Developer Access

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have added API Connect as a service on Bluemix. I am getting a message that states "Looks like you don't have developer access in this Bluemix space."  How do I fix this so that I can move on?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue is when you provisioned API Connect from the catalog, it was most likely provisioned using the old UI. After it's provisioned API Connect forwards the user to the new UI and info about the ORG/Space is lost during this transition. As others have mentioned the work around is to simply log into the new UI experience and change the org / space to the same org / space where APIC was provisioned. For all new provisions of API Connect, you should be provisioning with the new Bluemix UI experience.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "CREATE" -> you will redirect to new experience UI --> click on login on bottom of the page -> click on CREATE again.

Comment: I have already created the service. I need to get to the sandbox page, but I cannot get that far because the service says I am not  a developer, which makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, following my steps you should be able to launch the dashboard as well. This is a workaround to launch the service in new experience UI. click on login again on bottom of the page and create again. (not from catalog page).

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. It turned out that after clicking on the API Connect service the org and space changed. From the page saying "Looks like you don't have developer access in this Bluemix space" simply click on the icon on top right and change the org / space to the correct ones (the ones containing the service instance).

I did it just once and now every time I try to access again the correct space is loaded.